# Spring nested transactions - why do I need to clear the EntityManager?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a service calling into a Spring Data `CrudRepository`. The service method is marked as `@Transactional`. This method calls a private method that is annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. I am using AspectJ mode, so private methods are supported.

Pseudo-code:

```
@Transactional
public void updateIt( Object o )
{
  // call private method that is annotated with REQUIRES_NEW
  doUpdateInRepo( o );

 em.clear(); // Why do I need this here?      


  // Ask everything from repo again
  Collection all = repo.findAll();
  notifyListenersOfUpdate(all);
}

@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)
private doUpdateInRepo( o )
{
    repo.save( o ) // repo is a CrudRepository
}
```

What I don't understand is that outside of the private method, but still inside the service method, the changes done in the nested transaction are not visible. Only when I explicitly call `EntityManager.clear()` first, then the repository method `findAll` will return the updated results.

Any idea why this `clear()` is needed? I thought the nested transaction would commit and the outer transaction would "see" all changes done in the transaction?

I am using Spring 4.1.5.

Comment: which transactionmanager do you use? according to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW REQUIRES_NEW does not work out of the box for all transactionmanagers

Comment: I think if you don't `clear()` first, the `findAll()` will just grab the old ones from the cache.

Comment: I am using the `JpaTransactionManager`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have enabled compile-time or load-time weaving as detailed [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

The default mode "proxy" processes annotated beans to be proxied using Spring’s AOP framework (following proxy semantics, as discussed above, applying to method calls coming in through the proxy only). The alternative mode "aspectj" instead weaves the affected classes with Spring’s AspectJ transaction aspect, modifying the target class byte code to apply to any kind of method call. **AspectJ weaving requires spring-aspects.jar in the classpath as well as load-time weaving (or compile-time weaving) enabled. (See the section called “Spring configuration” for details on how to set up load-time weaving.)**